# (2019) Only allow Firefox to set cookies on specific sites

Tags: firefox

I'm having a bit of a difficult time finding a 2019 answer to this question.

I have a few sites I want to keep cookies for (to stay signed in), but for other sites I don't want them to be able to set cookies at all. I also don't want Firefox to remember download, browser history, cache any data, allow tracking cookies, etc.

However, there no longer appears to be an `Accept cookies from websites` option under History ([as seen here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1200198)), with cookies instead getting their own section in privacy settings. Whenever I click the `Manage Permissions...` button in the Cookies section and add a website to allow in the list it is cleared when I restart the browser. I do not have `Always use private browsing mode` enabled and `Clear history when Firefox closes` is not configured to delete cookies.

Is there a I can configure Firefox to only allow cookies from certain sites but not remember any other data?